# How do I create a custom ATC check that runs on releasing a transport request?

Tags: abap

I need to understand how ATC checks in ABAP will be created and how they can be run. I don't speak about semantical checks of the source code that could be realized via ATC, but about a **functional** ATC checks. Example: it would be enough for me to have an ATC check that will be started during each and every transport request and would test if a table XY has more that 1000 entries. Just as an example.

I know that there are some blogs about ATC like https://blogs.sap.com/2012/10/18/getting-started-with-the-abap-test-cockpit-for-developers/
and I understand that creating an ATC check I have to derive the test class from CL_CI_TEST_ROOT. But knowing this, it is still not clear to me how to come to an example I've described.

Does somebody know where can I find a "hello world" example for such kind of ATC checks?

Comment: ATC is a tool developed over the old Code Inspector tool, so you should go for blog posts which describe how to create your own Code Inspector checks. You can trigger checks when releasing transport requests, it's also documented.